# How can I fetch 2D array from HTML frontend to the flask end?

Tags: python, html, flask, frontend, backend

```py
import numpy as np

# Example input data
input_data = [[3758096389, 0, 114456999, 0, 0, 0, 2601295.432, 10001143, 2601295.432, 10001143, 1, 0, 0.393160754, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0]]

# input_data = X_test
import joblib

# Convert the input data to a numpy array
# input_array = np.array(input_data)

ensemble_model=joblib.load('/content/ensemble_model_3_DT_RF.pkl')

# Make predictions using the ensemble model
ensemble_predictions = ensemble_model.predict(input_array)

# Print the predicted labels
print("Predicted Labels:", ensemble_predictions)
```

The code above is working fine in Google colab, but when I try to take input through a html front end I am getting error as -

```
TypeError
TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

So can anyone please tell me how to fetch a feature array from the HTML frontend to the flask?

```py
def predictFunction():
    data = request.form['feature_array'] # Retrieve the feature array value as a string
    
    # Convert the feature array string to a 2D list
    data = np.array(eval(data))
    data = data.tolist()
    # input_data = request.json
    # data = input_data["feature_array"]
    # input_data = request.form['feature_array']
    selected_model = request.form['model']
    # feature_array = ast.literal_eval(input_data)
    # input_data = [[float(x) for x in row.split(",")] for row in input_data.split("\n") if row]
    # data=[data]
    # data="["+data+"]"
    # data=np.array([feature_array])
    
    if selected_model == 'Ensemble Model 1':
        # Perform prediction using ensemble model 1
        prediction = Ensemble_model_1.predict(data)
    elif selected_model == 'Ensemble Model 2':
        # Perform prediction using ensemble model 2
        prediction = Ensemble_model_2.predict(data)
    elif selected_model == 'Ensemble Model 3':
        # Perform prediction using ensemble model 3
        prediction = Ensemble_model_3.predict(data)
    else:
        prediction =  selected_model
```

This is what I am trying.

```html
<form method="POST" action="/predictFunction">
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="feature_array">Feature Array:</label>
    <input type="text" id="feature_array" class="form-control" name="feature_array" placeholder="Enter the feature array" value="">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-dark">Predict</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is your HTML? What does the data look like coming from HTML? How are you sending the data?

Comment: <div class="mb-3">
                                <label for="feature_array">Feature Array:</label>
                                <input type="text" id="feature_array" class="form-control" name="feature_array"
                                    placeholder="Enter the feature array" value="">
                            </div>

so this is my html

Comment: Update the question and add relevant information. Are the back-slashes (before the list braces) supposed to be in the first python block of code? If you did that to render the code instead of hyperlinks, I already fixed the rendering by adding three successive back-ticks. You can edit your question to remove the back-slashes if you wish.

Comment: [[3758096389, 0, 114456999, 0, 0, 0, 2601295.432, 10001143, 2601295.432, 10001143, 1, 0, 0.393160754, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0]]
here's the correct array

Comment: <form method="POST" action="/predictFunction">
<div class="mb-3"> <label for="feature_array">Feature Array:</label> <input type="text" id="feature_array" class="form-control" name="feature_array" placeholder="Enter the feature array" value=""> </div>
     <button> class="btn btn-dark">Predict</button>
  </form>

this is how i am sending data